# Abrir una Url dentro de una Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la siguiente pregunta: Como Abrir una Url dentro de una Activity.

Esta activity es mi Activity_ Main, en ella tengo una imagen de una cardview con Url, pero cuando le doy click abre las opciones de los browser, pero lo que quiero es que se abran estos link dentro de de mi aplicacion.

"He buscado tutoriales pero todos hablan de WebView" lo cierto es que no quiero una web view dentro de mi activity_main. Tengo una AcivityWeb que funciona bien para otros usos como ir a mi web desde un FAB, pero no es la Main.

Importante! Estos link vienen desde la firebase.

Answer (score 3):

Usa `WebViewClient`, y dentro del método `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` cargas en la misma vista el url, de esta forma al dar clic en un link se obligará a cargar dentro del `WebView`. :

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");
webView.setWebViewClient((new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //Al dar clic en un link se obligará a cargar dentro del WebView.
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }));
```

Cargamos la página dentro del `WebView`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar click en un enlace, este se abrirá dentro del mismo `WebView`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Has de emplear el WebViewClient para no salir de la aplicación. No estoy seguro de que sea esto lo que necesitas.

```
    WebView appWeb = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //Habilitamos el javaScript y el zoom
    appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //Cargamos el enlace definido
    appWeb.loadUrl(direccion_web);
    //Este método es para que el navegador se quede en nuestra aplicación
    appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       return false;
    }
```