# Habilitar navegación web dentro de la aplicación con WebView Android

Tags: android, webview, webview-android

estoy mostrando una url en un `WebView`, esto me permite que se muestre la página sin salir de la aplicación, sin embargo cuando sigo navegando dentro de otras urls de la misma página es cuando ya se sale y la muestra en el navegador, únicamente la url que tengo configurada se muestra en el `WebView`.

Java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.virtual_apoyo_activity);

    String url="http://virtual.uniagustiniana.edu.co/AVAP/login/index.php";
    WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.wvvirtual_apoyo);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.tecnologias.uniagustinianaapp.VirtualApoyo">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wvvirtual_apoyo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Muchas gracias,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes definir un [**WebViewClient**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) a tu `WebView` y mediante el método `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` realizarías lo que deseas, por ejemplo:

```
 WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.wvvirtual_apoyo);
 view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 //view.loadUrl(url);
 view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(url); //Define el url
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Trate de buscar si había una pregunta sobre esto, encontré esta pero sin embargo no tiene respuesta aceptada:

[Abrir una Url dentro de una Activity](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42388/abrir-una-url-dentro-de-una-activity/42397#42397)

Comment: Genial muchas gracias, si me puedes ayudar con esta otra pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109327/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-icono-en-cada-%C3%ADtem-del-men%C3%BA-con-recyclerview